# is it accepted to name a php varible like $_xxx?

Tags: php, variables, naming-conventions

i'm building a site and i included a settings file named "settings.php", 
i think it's look cool to register a global var by the name: $_SETTINGS
as an array of the site settings (db_name, db_pass....etc)
as so:

```
<?php
    $_SETTINGS = array();
    $_SETTINGS['DB_HOSTNAME']= 'localhost';
    $_SETTINGS['DB_NAME'] = 'db_test';
    $_SETTINGS['DB_USERNAME'] = 'db_user';
    $_SETTINGS['DB_PASSWORD'] = 'p422w0rd';
 ?>
```

and then access those settings on the sub pages... by accessing $_SETTINGS...

this code works just fine,
but i'm curious is it acceptable among the php programmers community to name your own variables as $_ ?
or my code considered as a bad design?

thanks

Comment: its your code, do what you want

Comment: That's really just a personal preferences thing. Of course, a unique global like `$_SETTINGS` is practical and makes its purpose obvious. (It would be silly though, if you're splitting the other half of the application config out into the database still.)

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Comment: @Rizier123 your answer is accepted by me as the final answer -> naming a var $_SETTINGS is legal and fine, but may cause confusing to code readers with supoerglobals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but I wouldn't recommend it, since the [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) variables have also this pattern/prefix e.g. `$_SERVER`, `$_SESSION`, `$_GET` which then is maybe a bit confusing.

But according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). Technical you can do it:

> A **valid variable** name **starts** with a **letter or underscore**, **followed** by any number of **letters, numbers, or underscores**. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: **'[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'**

At the end it's a  personal preference what you do.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that this is bad idea. Better solution is create singleton class providing configuration all across your application.

Something like this:

```
class MyConfigProvider
{

    private $config = array();

    private static $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
            self::$instance = new self();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct(){}

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->config;
    }

    public function setConfig(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }
}
```

You can get configuration in all places in your app by

```
$config = MyConfigProvier::getInstance()->getConfig();
```

It isn't the best solution but it is easy to implement and it works

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, can you tell be please why is it better then a settings array included as setting file in index.php? why does it matters? i want to understand better...

Comment: whats are the benefits of using this class?, plus you said it's not the best solution.. what is the best solution?

Comment: hi, it is little cleaner solution than using global variables. Global variables are very dangerous to use out of global scope because any change on those global variables (e.g. typo in your code) can make unexpected behaviour in different component of your program. With this you separate original config data from rest out of your application.

Comment: the best solution is completely avoid to singleton classes, but I thing to do it, you have to rewrite basic logic of your application. Try to read something about dependency injection.

Comment: hi, i'm a bit confuse, the best solution is to AVOID singleton classes? my codes always messy, but i try to improve it every day... in my new site i'm still in the ui styling part, and just moved to the logic... so how do you recommend me to do the settings part the best way possible?

Comment: i'm also using this same method of array in included file to multi-language support... like: "en.lang.php" : $_LANG['PAGE_TITLE']='English page title';

Comment: to the first question: singleton classes have one ugly feature: in larger project can be situation when you expect some state of this singleton object (loaded config in this case) but logic responsible for this action was not called yet. I thing the best solution is to create instance of some config holder and inject it into all factory classes. See Zend Framework 2, ServiceLocator class. Disadvantage of this approach is much more support code in your application (but if you write it well, it is reusable in other projects).

Comment: And the second question, my recommendation is do not write it yourself in PHP by use some prepared library. E.g. gettext module. It is PHP modules written in C/C++ and it will be much faster than your PHP code (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php). To create getttext definition files you can use Poedit: http://poedit.net/